# Best way to stiffen up floor

Tags: ceiling, floor, joists

While gutting my basement I want to strengthen my floor above to make it move less. Currently the floor above moves a lot when people walk around, making it really loud in the basement and causes stuff to move in living room which the floor belongs to.

The floor had a small amount of wooden bridging and some 1x3s running perpendicular to the joists that the drywall was attached to.

I also added some steel bridging from Simpson Strong-Tie that I read good things on, but these didn't appear to make much difference.

I think a big portion of the problem might be the 3 lengths of ducting that run the length of the room. (One ends before the window in the basement, the other 2 run into the cantilever in the living room upstairs.) Perhaps these long ducts are turning the floor into several parts that move on their own?

Do I have any options to make this better, or am I stuck?

Thanks

[image: Picture of the floor from below]

Comment: Any drastic change will not necessarily help a bouncy floor but certainly will cause a lot of headaches and money. The noise is mainly caused by the vibration, one solution is to add mass to the floor. I would suggest adding insulation in the joist space, and rigid foam between ceiling supports.

Comment: Are you willing to put down new floor on room above the basement?  If not, there's probably not a whole lot you can do.

Comment: @RibaldEddie room above the basement has hardwood that is in really good shape, so I guess not.

Oh well, thanks anyways.

Comment: Are there nails popping up through the flooring in the floor above?   The only mechanism you might think about is how you can draw the tops of the joists and the bottom of the subfloor tighter together from below.

Comment: What is the size, spacing, and span of the joists? What is the wood floor above, species, size, shape (rectangular, T&G, etc.) ?

Comment: you'd do well to answer lee sam's questions.

Comment: @LeeSam It's 2x8 joists, 16" on center. It's a 13' span where there is a beam where the joists in this room end and more start.

The hardwood above is maple, it is T&G. It is 3/4". It is on 3/4" ply subfloor.

Comment: How old is the house / floor assembly?

Comment: House is from the early 70s, the hardwood was installed about 10 years ago.

Comment: When the floor was installed 10 years ago, was there a new subfloor also? I’m guessing not…

Comment: Anyway I agree with Lee that it’s not the joists being structurally unsound — unless some structure was removed in the basement by an overzealous renovation. Instead over time (50 years now) all the wood has gone through many many seasonal expansion and contraction, and that’s basically loosened everything. 50 years ago they would have just nailed the subfloor to the joists (no glue) and over time the mechanical fastening just stops holding.

Comment: That duct work has nothing to do with the problem, other than possibly contributing to noise as pieces move. They haven't "turned the floor into several parts that move on their own".

Comment: @marcusds - Just a point of reference.  My house, built in the mid 1950's, has 2x8 floor joists on 16" centers, with spans close just bit shorter than yours - 12' in most areas maybe 13' in an added bedroom.  I do not have an issue with the floors being bouncy or trampolining.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the floor joists. They are sized to support about 74 lbs. per square foot (psf) depending on the species and grade of the wood.  The Code only requires about 50 psf. I’d leave the joists alone unless there are notches in the lumber.

I doubt the problem is with the subfloor. Almost all plywood is rated for 16” span for a floor, unless it’s 1/4” thick.

However, I’m certain it’s your T&G flooring that’s making the noise. Things I’d check: 1) Is the flooring installed over a slip sheet or vapor barrier, 2) Is the wood flooring perfectly flat, 3) Was the wood flooring milled correctly or is it a “second”?

1. There needs to be a slip sheet (building paper) or a vapor barrier (slick sheet) to allow the wood flooring to move slightly when stepped on. If this was not installed then you could hear clicking when stepped on.
2. If the flooring is not perfectly flat and laying down then you’ll hear clicking when stepped on.
3. The T&G components are supposed to fit tight. If the tongue is loose, it will click in the groove portion when stepped on. You can test this by holding a tongue board vertical and pressing a groove board into it. If it slides down then it’s not made correctly… it’s a second.

Comment: I have never seen nor read any installation for nail down t&g hardwood floor that suggests placing building paper or vapor barrier directly underneath the flooring. The OP could say when the floor was laid and if it has always made noise— my guess is no. My guess is that the noises started occurring years after installation and are due to changes in moisture and settling over time. A lot of old houses have squeaky floors and imho it’s almost always due to movement of the subfloor.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, it makes a lot of sense. No, there is no sheets under the flooring. It's not a clicking, or squeaking sound the boards make. It's movement throughout the floor. Like if on the coffee table there are glasses, and as someone walks away the floor moves enough the glasses clink against each other. In the room below someone's normal walking sounds like they are purposefully stomping around. Things like that. Do you think that could be cause by the flooring? If so, I guess I'll just have to live with it until it needs to be replaced (in probably a long while.)

Comment: @marcusds Insulation in the floor cavity will help with sound transmittance. But the movement is another matter. With the joists and spacing you have, there should not be any deflection from someone walking around unless there were massive integrity problems with the joists, but they look fine in the photo (no notches, no mold or rot, no termite damage, no powder post beetle holes, etc.). (1/2)

Comment: @marcusds My guess is the subfloor was not screwed down, but nailed or glued. That and it looks like flooring staples were used instead of nails. Staples are great for initial install, but they perform less well than nails over time. See if you can't remove a couple rows of the flooring (you'll need to take the molding/trim off the edge of the room above that has the tongue side of the flooring pieces), and check if the subfloor was nailed or screwed. During this step, you can also check the fit of the flooring pieces as Lee Sam recommends. (2/2)

Comment: @Lee Sam - I agree with all of your comments.  But they don't address OP's main complaint, that "Currently the floor above moves a lot when people walk around, making it really loud in the basement and causes stuff to move in living room which the floor belongs to".  That sure sound like joists flexing, and not the hardwood rubbing against the underlayment.

Comment: I would agree with @SteveSh that if the floor is moving so much that _glasses on a table rattle_ when someone walks on the floor, then _something_ is undersized or compromised. Either that or the flooring is just sitting on the joists and isn't nailed/screwed down at all.

Comment: @SteveSh  Actually I think it does address the Op’s main complaint. As they say, “the floor above moves”. Now we could argue about if that means the “flooring” or the “structural floor system”. I can assure you that if the joists are sized and spaced as the OP indicates, then it’s not the floor flexing when a single person walks across the floor. However, if the tongue does not fit tight in the groove, it will snap to a new position when a person walks on it. (I wonder if it’s worse when several people walk on it.)

Comment: @FreeMan  Please see response to SteveSh. When the flooring snaps to a new position because the tongue moved into a new position, I’m sure it could rattle dishes on nearby tables.

Comment: Do structural engineers have equipment to study the vibration modes of this type of construction? I can imagine a vibration driver and a vibration detector both of which could be placed in various location around a room. Could it be determined whether the vibratory movement is in the plane of the floor or is perpendicular to the floor?

Comment: @Jim Stewart Good question. Only through trial and error I suppose.

Comment: Are the ends of these joists resting on a sill plate on the top of a concrete foundation wall? It might help to show pics of both ends.

Comment: @JimStewart one end is on the sill plate on top of foundation wall, the other on a beam where more joists run the rest of the distance of the house.

Comment: Is the floor on the other side of the beam also one that gets into vibration when walked on? Is the floor area that vibrates the only one in the house that does this?

Comment: You could experiment by supporting  the joists from below (e.g., midway between the sill plate end and the beam) with a temporary beam supported  by adjustable length steel posts or other means. Of course, you wouldn't want to strain the floor.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get those joists not to flex is to turn your entire floor into a torsion box.  These are common with wood workers as a flat and true workbenches.  To bend the bottom of the joist has to be able to deflect.  If you used construction adhesive and screwed sheets of plywood to the bottoms of the joists, forming a shell, the joists bottoms would not be able to deflect.  I have pondered doing this myself under several rooms in my house, but have yet to pull the trigger.

Comment: The joists are strapped on the bottom, so some of that work is being done already. It’s not quite the same as full sheathing but it does make it less likely that the problem is the joists.

Comment: I don't think that strapping is doing anything.  The bottom of the joists need to be rigid along their length.  I have a few spots I want to do this too, but it may be a while before I can report back any findings.

Comment: yeah I agree the strapping isn’t doing much at all. The OP should be able to observe the deflection with the aid of an assistant walking above while observing below with a level or plumb bob and a string line.

Answer (score -2):

I am not an expert, but here are my ideas. The floor moves up-down (I guess) as opposed to left-right or forward-backward. It means that:

- there is space between the floor and the supporting beams;
- the (horizontal) supporting beams are too elastic.

So some solutions would be:

- re-make all the joints using metal clamps ("L" shaped, or something more specialized), and nuts and bolts. Nails and screws for wood do not have a lot of force to do the job, and allow some small movement - just enough for you to feel and hear it.
- re-apply the flooring, adding some insulator under it. You might reduce the noise coming from the floor touching the supporting beams. The supporting beams might still make some noise.
- install some vertical poles to support the support structure. This might be inconvenient if the area under the room should be a garage. *This solution would work against the [**elasticity of wood**](https://extension.okstate.edu/fact-sheets/strength-properties-of-wood-for-practical-applications.html), which would cause micro-bends and micro-movements - leading to noises.*

---

To provide some "science" to my "theory" about the nails, I provide some info from [**this page on Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightingale_floor).

> Nightingale floors (鴬張り or 鶯張り, uguisubari) are floors that make a chirping sound when walked upon. These floors were used in the hallways of some temples and palaces, the most famous example being Nijō Castle, in Kyoto, Japan. **Dry boards naturally creak under pressure**, but these floors were built in a way that the flooring nails rub against a jacket or clamp, causing chirping noises. It is unclear if the design was intentional. It seems that, at least initially, the effect arose by chance. An information sign in Nijō castle states that "**The singing sound is not actually intentional, stemming rather from the movement of nails against clumps in the floor caused by wear and tear over the years**". Legend has it that the squeaking floors were used as a security device, assuring that none could sneak through the corridors undetected.

---

You wrote in a comment:

> "nails and screws for wood do not have a lot of force to do the job" According to whom? Nails have done just fine for hundreds of years in the building industry, and screws are far superior even to them. Modern day nails (galvanized) and modern day screws especially are far superior and more than enough to prevent a floor from ever moving/squeaking.

Now, if the nails and wood-screws do such an excellent job stiffening your floor, "far superior" to nuts and bolts, then why do you need extra stiffening? I understand that you have the problem, but you might look at it from a sub-optimal POV.

---

On [**this site**](https://themasterscraft.com/5-things-floor-says-squeaks/) they discuss about squeaky floors. One hidden culprit might be the humidity of the house / area - which affects the properties of the wood (see also the other linked article). A (less usual?) solution proposed is to actually **use glue** - in order to combat all possible movements. Just read and follow the links there, you will find some interesting info.

Comment: "nails and screws for wood do not have a lot of force to do the job" According to whom? Nails have done just fine for hundreds of years in the building industry, and screws are far superior even to them. Modern day nails (galvanized) and modern day screws especially are far superior and more than enough to prevent a floor from ever moving/squeaking.

Comment: @TylerH: I added to my answer. Shortly: according to the Japanese ;) Nails can keep houses upright successfully, but cannot keep pieces of anything tight enough over long periods of time. Especially wood - which changes its properties as it gets older / drier

Comment: So... your source is itself an unsourced tourist plaque about one floor in a Japanese castle that was built over 400 years ago, **where the floor was specifically constructed to make noise**... that's not particularly convincing or relevant to how (western, especially) construction practices/materials over the last several hundred years have worked, or to the common practice of *not* installing squeaky floors that pretty much everyone else prefers.

Comment: No, my source is my own experience, although limited. The link I provided is a "proof" that other people reached the same conclusion like myself.